# How do I troubleshoot a WCF service with failing load tests?

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-4.0

I have a WCF 4 service running on IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008), deployed to a development server. The service works when I run a small website that consumes the service (click a button, the page calls the service, data is returned. It's very basic).

I also created some unit tests that call the service and placed them into a load test. In a nutshell, the "unit tests" call the service and write the `byte[]` streamed back from the service to a file. The service performs as expected when running the load test.

The problem is the load test fails after a very small number of iterations.  Sometimes foour calls are successful, other times after five calls. Again, individually, the tests run fine but when I put them together to simulate a live environment (multiple users, multiple test iterations) this problem appears.

The exception thrown is:

```
Test method TestProject1.UnitTest1.RunReport threw exception: 
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yy/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

**Update #1:**
I just set the test iteration to 10 (run the test 10x) and the constant user load to 1. The test was able to complete succesfully. This was using the most basic of the unit tests. The second, more complicated test, was omitted for this run.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your application event log (eventvwr.exe). Assuming you're operating in a mostly-normal environment, there will be an entry for the server-side error.